# How to get URL parameters from angularjs $location in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm showing a database table using ruby on rails, and I'd like to sort the columns whenever I click on the column title. 
My idea was to call an angularjs function that adds a parameter like `?sort_by=id` to the url and get it back in my ruby controller to do the ordered request, but it seems like it's not working.

Here is the part of my users.html.haml file which calls the function :

```
%th
  %button{'ng-click': 'sort_by("product")'}
```

My angularjs function (users.controller.js) :

```
$scope.sort_by = function(str){
    $location.search({sort_by: 'product'});
    $window.location.reload();
}
```

And index function in users_controller.rb

```
def index
  @users = User.all 
  max_per_page = 50
  puts params
  paginate @users.size, max_per_page do |limit, offset|
    render json: @users.limit(limit).offset(offset)
  end
end
```

When I click on the button, it reloads the page with `?sort_by=product` in the url and calls the index function, but `puts params` still returns `{"subdomain"=>"admin", "controller"=>"admin/users", "action"=>"index"}`

How can I make this work ? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I used an $http get request with params and it finally worked, in case it helps someone :

```
                $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: 'users',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    params: {
                        'sort_by': 'products.name',
                    },
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json"
                    }
                }).success(function(response){
                    console.log('succes');
                }).error(function(error){
                    console.log('err');
                });
```

and then in index method in users_controller.rb :

```
  puts request.params['sort_by'] if !request.params['sort_by'].nil?
```